# What to do when mono returns an error "Could not load file or assembly"

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I tried running an .exe file on a Mac which the developer said requires .NET Framework 4.5.2 with

```
mono oms-client.exe
```

it comes with an error message

```
The entry point method could not be loaded due to Could not load file or assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies
```

What can I do?

Comment: I don’t know for sure but PresentationFramework sounds like WPF which is not available for Mac.

Comment: It is impossible to run WPF apps on non Windows platforms. https://blog.lextudio.com/the-story-about-net-cross-platform-ui-frameworks-dd4a9433d0ea

Answer (score -4, accepted):

> the developer said requires .NET Framework 4.5.2

If that's the case it cannot be installed on a Mac.  .NET Framework requires a Windows OS.  To quote Microsoft's website on .NET:

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download

> .NET Core is a cross-platform version of .NET for building websites,
> services, and console apps.

> .NET Framework is a Windows-only version of .NET for building any type
> of app that runs on Windows.

Specifically you'd need a Windows Vista SP2+ OS.  Compatibility table here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/get-started/system-requirements